# AngularJS ng-include caching

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i like to include templates with the `ng-include` attribute. I like to know if the templates getting cached while using the the same url multiple times.

```
<div ng-include src="'./Views/temp.html'"></div> //get request temp.html
<div ng-include src="'./Views/temp.html'"></div> //load from cache
```

Comment: you could check it using browser network capture.For the first request the status must be 200, if the second request has status 304 or we don't have second request. We can be sure that the template is cached

Comment: I believe `$templateCache` service does it http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

Comment: the html is cached, and no extra requests are created. I came here actually trying to find how to overcome the cache..

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Caching *is* typically used - but its not on the part of angular but instead on the part of the browser. You can see this by running Fiddler and seeing what happens when your page loads. If you get a 304 result code back from the server it means that the page hasn't changed - so it will be pulled from cache.

**Force Reload**

The only good way to consistently force a reload is to add query string as follows (you can replace "i" with any variable you would like and the numbers just need to be random - not previously used numbers):

```
<div ng-include src="'./Views/temp.html?i=1000'"></div> // get request temp.html
<div ng-include src="'./Views/temp.html?i=1001'"></div> // force the page to load!
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: it is actually being cached by angular, please see the angular documentation for $templateCache:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

Comment: @Laurel You are correct, but as this is a javascript cache, it will be cleared simply by closing and opening the browser again. The browser cache on the other hand can only be "automatically" cleared in the manner I showed above. Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: I want to add an easy way to fully (really fully) a website in chrome is to open up the debug console with F12 and then right click on the reload button on the top of the screen and choose the last option. This is needed since Shift+F5 doens't seem to clear the template cache

Comment: Another solution is to ignore the browser cache completely by preloading HTML fragments into the `$templateCache` when the application loads. This has the added benefit of reducing the number of requests (you don't even have to hit the browser cache at all). The downside is running more JS on startup. There's grunt plugins for this (like https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates) but it's fairly simple to make your own as well. We were using maven and it was literally ~100 LOC to make a plugin.

Comment: To force reload in Chrome you can open developer tools and from the settings page (gear icon) choose to disable cache while dev-tools open. Seems to work for me.

Comment: Template caching is creating problem in my case. View is not updating even if there is change in template. Any solution? adding version everytime is hectic, there should be some way to solve the problem automatic.

Comment: Have you considered using a tool such as gulp/grunt to update your version numbers?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I opened the "Incognito Window" still it was showing me the cached version. I inspected the same and found the .html pages were having 200 status.

One easy way to overcome this problem is to use "Clear Browser cache" in the "Network" tab.
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will fix the issue for you momentarily, until you make another change. 
 Public users of your site will not know this and will have to wait for their cache to invalidate before seeing your most recent updates.