# AngularJS use data from one page to print a report in another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

I have a domain object on which multiple procedures might be performed, each procedure might (or might not) have pre-configured reports to be generated.

When viewing the details page of the domain object, a list of the performed procedures is displayed with the corresponding reports to be generated for them. The reports would be launched in another browser tab when clicking their hyperlinks.

[image: procedure-section-in-the-ui]

Suppose that *all* the information needed by the reports is already present in a `$scope.myDomainObject` of the current details page, how can I take advantage of this object in the report page without re-fetching the same data from the server again.

---

#### EDIT

The report is a simple Html page styled with CSS to match the A4 paper format. I wanted to use directives instead of opening a new page in another tab, but since the reports are dynamically configured in the DB that wouldn't work. Maybe if directive templates weren't cached I would've used a dynamic templateUrl for them.

Comment: As @drew_w says the best approach you can get with angular is having a SPA but if you don't want to change your application, take a look to cookies manage with angular, you can pass your varible between tabs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Answer (score 2):

If you place the data into a service, which is a singleton, you can inject the service into the page of each controller. An example of what that looks like:

```
myApp.factory('Data', function(){
    return { DataField: '' };
});

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Data) {
    $scope.myDomainObject = Data;
});

myApp.controller('PrintCtrl', function($scope, Data) {
    $scope.myDomainObject = Data;
});
```

The limitation of this approach is that you need to have a SPA (Single Page Application). This doesn't sound like it is the case if you are opening in other tabs or windows. If the reports aren't extremely complicated you could consider moving them into a template file and loading that as a view in the current tab rather than as an entirely new tab.

Hope that helps put you on the right track. Best of luck!

**Note** - Based on the question edit you can still use a template file. You just need to add a query string parameter to make sure that the browser doesn't cache the result. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935446/angularjs-ng-include-caching/21935622#21935622) for details on that.