# How to detect whether user reached webpage by link, ctrl+r or ctrl+shift+r reloads

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http, caching

How can I detect how a user reached a page? Link, reload (clear-cached or not?) in chrome?

I am using angular. My response header contains:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=3600
Last-Modified:Tue, 19 May 2015 06:19:02 GMT
```

1) This behaves as expected, when I reload (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) the request for all files contain

```
Cache-Control:max-age=0
If-Modified-Since:Tue, 19 May 2015 06:19:02 GMT
```

If the file is not modified I get

```
Status Code:304 Not Modified
```

2) If I reload with (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) or reach the website first time I get

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Pragma:no-cache
```

and the file is fetched anew.

3) If I go to the webpage through a link it loads files from cache if they have been fetched <3600 seconds before also.

```
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
```

**EXCEPT html files which I load with ng-include src="''"**

They are always fetched from cache. I have to delete the cache of the whole browser for them to be fetched newly. Even <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> doesn't work. Disable cache in developer tools works as in it stops caching.

So I added somethings to my angular app config.

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
```

After this only html templates are always fetched newly. I have noticed that chrome also uses below two request headers

```
Cache-Control: 'no-cache'
Pragma: 'no-cache'
```

and such files obey cache rules, except .html templates. Why?

If I change the above lines to

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=x';
```

then it works as expected, fetch from cache till expires and then check if not modified on server from cache. But this way it will not obey the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> reload where chrome sends

```
Cache-Control:max-age=0
```

So how can I detect how the user reached the webpage in chrome/firefox/etc.?

Another alternative is to make angular $http always use the same headers like chrome when it fetches a file? right? That is always mimic browser http calls

How fool-proof is checking `document.referrer`?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [AngularJS ng-include caching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935446/angularjs-ng-include-caching)

Comment: What do you want to use this information for? Usage stats, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, accessing headers of requests spawned by the browser is impossible from JavaScripts point of view. The browser simply does not allow you to see those requests.

For XHR requests, like the ones Angular uses to fetch its templates, whether you pressed Ctrl+R, Ctrl+Shift+R or just pressed a link makes no difference since that only acts on the initial resource (the document) and all files directly linked from there.

The referrer is not really something you can rely on, since some browsers keep the referrer on refresh, some don't, so you can't see a difference between the reload and the link click. Also if you treat an empty referrer as a cache-less reload, people coming to your page by typing in the URL themselves could never get a cached version.

The only way to see which headers the browser sends, and thus adjusting your caching method to would be to have some server-side script in for example PHP check them and write the right caching option into the response in either a hidden form field or a cookie or a generate JavaScript file. If you're using this option you'll want to make sure the PHP script that checks the caching headers is requested by the browser itself and not through XHR.

Then again, allowing your initial load method to influence the requests later on, made through AJAX might not even be what you want. If this is a problem you're encountering during development for example, it might be best to just keep the developer console open, undock it from your window and keep it in the background.

If your users are seeing stale templates on production, you're better off using your server to set up caching for HTML files, and decrease the cache time and use ETag settings according to your needs. Modern browsers will always respect the settings your server returns when determining how to cache their requests, and so will Angular when requesting templates.

Lastly, if you're seeing stale templates during the application runtime, that's because Angular will keep a template in memory after its inital load and never request it again unless you specifically ask it to through the $templateCache.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bruteforce "hack-ish" way of preventing caching 100% - to add a query-string parameter to the URL. Could be

```
<div ng-include src="'./myfile.html?random_number=123456'"></div>
```

(Sometimes even adding the same query-string parameter prevents browser from caching a resource)

I'm not a big expert on AngularJS, but I think you can use Angular "expressions" in the `"src"` attribute, something like this:

```
$scope.myRandomNumber = new Date().getTime(); //milliseconds since 1970
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<div ng-include src="'./myfile.html?random_number=' + myRandomNumber"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure, but i don't think you are on the right track to solve this issue. you should focus on caching mechanisms. detecting keys or page load scheme and modifying cache headers according to this seems too much trouble, not worth the issue.

but for the record. i was thinking you could use some keypress library for angular and localstorage on the browser. so you could identify which keys were pressed and write that information to localstorage.

on page open check storage. if it is

empty -> it might be link or first page open

not empty -> whatever you wrote to localstorage last time keys were pressed

and clear storage.

check these

https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys/

https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Comment: even better in my opinion, don't write to the disk. Just use sessionStorage (memory-only, expires when you close your browser. It looks like that angular library supports it)

Answer (score 0):

The question involves two parts, proper use of caching and ways to detect if user landed on webpage from outside or refreshed the page. These are not necesarily related, here an answer will be given as regards the detection of web visit versus reload (e.g `ctrl+r` or `ctrl+shift+r`).

The main difference is that a reload **will not affect the current page url** whatever this has been set to. So this can be exploited to detect if a reload has happended. A way to do that cross-browser and without relying on features which may or may not be accessible from javascript is this:

1. After page load, add specific randomised hash to the url e.g `#uuid=AGHJHFG64675`
2. Save the same hash using `cookies` or `local storage` (if available)
3. On page load see if cookie (or local storage) has the hash and that it matches the url hash (if present).
4. if these conditions are met, you know a reload has been made and not an external visit.

Pros and Cons of the approach:

1. Does not rely on inaccessible request information or similar
2. It is cross-browser
3. Not easy to detect simple reload from cache vs reload bypassing cache (still thinking about this)
4. User can manualy manipulate and change the url hash before doing reload. This cannot be checked, but does it really matter?? For example, user wants to bypass this procedure on purpose (e.g testing)
5. Url hash may change for other reasons due to page interaction (e.g click a link with `href=#target`). This is not handled but it is easy to handle also this case, by adding a handler on `hashchange` and reset the hash key if it is missing

Answer (score 0):

If you're only concerned with link / reload via ctrl-r then I'd suggest watching the keyboard on the document element, and if ctrl+r is pressed then save a timestamp in sessionStorage. Note that if you're using a keyboard event then it won't know if someone clicked the reload button on the browser (and you also won't know if they've remapped the reload key combo etc).

If you're only concerned with link / reload (no matter how), then I'd suggest a setInterval saving a timestamp to sessionStorage every second.

Either way, on page load check the timestamp against the current time and 1. if it exists and 2. if it's recent (last 5 seconds maybe?) then assume that it's a reload. It may be wrong, but hopefully not by much.

Things to bear in mind include the fact that some browsers (such as Firefox, or various Chrome extensions) leave tabs unloaded (but with sessionStorage intact) until needed - so the timestamp will exist but be old - which would probably mean either browser refresh or restart as opposed to tab reload.

If going the keyboard route don't forget that OSX has different modifier keys to Windows / Linux, and tablets etc don't use them at all.